# How to connect a unity code and a wpf code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visualization

I am new on Stackoverflow and thanks for every help in advance.

I created a WPF project to read pressure datas from a force measurement plate. I realized that the WPF application is too slow in order to use it as a fluently running visualization.

Now (after some recommendations)I want to use Unity. Unfortunately I am a greenhorn in unity. 
My code delivers the relevant data in `var data=new List<Tuple<int,int,double>>();`. In addition the data are live datas thus the List is dynamically.

I noticed that you can add scripts to assets in unity. 
What is an easy way to implement my code and use the List in unity? Or should I rewrite my code in the unity script that I get my measurements data in unity directly?

thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I suggest your re-write your code in Unity. If you still want to use both then look at the duplicated question.

Comment: But I tried to write my code in the unity project and I can work with Tuple thought I declared using System;

Comment: You can write an application in C# without Tuple. Modify your code to not require it. You can't use Tuple  because Unity supports up to ..NET 3.4 while Tuple  was added in .NET 4. You have to download **Unity 2017** if you want to use Tuple .